# AWS CLI on Windows won't work though using double quotes and escapes

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, command-prompt, aws-cli, aws-event-bridge

I made an Amazon Event Bridge rule and I wanted to attach targets on it using AWS CLI.

I knew that when you use json string in aws cli on windows 10 command prompt, you need to

1. Use double quotes.(Single quotes are now allowed.)
2. Put back slashes before double quotes except for the first and the last one.

so, I call this on command prompt

```
aws events put-targets --rule xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --targets "{\"Arn\":\"arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1:awsaccountid:automation-definition/AWS-StartEC2Instance\",\"Input\":\"{\"InstanceId\":[\"i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"]}\",\"Id\":\"aaaaaaaa\",\"RoleArn\":\"arn:aws:iam::awsaccountid:role/some-ssm-role\"}"
```

but got error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--targets': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 104 (char 103)
JSON received: {"Arn":"arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1:awsaccountid:automation-definition/AWS-StartEC2Instance","Input":"{"InstanceId":["i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]}","Id":"aaaaaaaa","RoleArn":"arn:aws:iam::awsaccountid:role/some-ssm-role"}
```

any suggestion?

p.s.
I made sure command below succeeded on Linux terminal.

```
aws events put-targets --rule xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --targets '{"Arn": "arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1:awsaccountid:automation-definition/AWS-StopEC2Instance","Input":"{\"InstanceId\":[\"i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"]}","Id":"aaaaaaaa","RoleArn":"arn:aws:iam::awsaccountid:role/some-ssm-role"}'
```

Comment: I suspect you should _not_ have quotes around the dictionary: `"{"InstanceId":["i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]}"` -- try removing those outer quotes, since you want to pass the _dictionary_ as an object rather than a string.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced the outer quotes
`,\"Input\":\"{\"InstanceId\":[\"i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"]}\",`  
as  
`,\"Input\":{\"InstanceId\":[\"i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"]},`  
  
but I still got another error:  
    
    
 `Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Targets[0].Input, value: OrderedDict([('InstanceId', ['i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'])]), type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Comment: This might help... Take a look at the PowerShell and Windows Command Prompt sections of: [Using quotation marks with strings in the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html)

Comment: I don't think it needs to be an array because the command above for Linux was not. Anyway I tried `aws events put-targets --rule xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --targets "[{the same dictionary}]"` and got `Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 105 (char 104)`

Comment: I have no idea why they are expecting comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the following:

```
aws events put-targets --rule xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --targets "{\"Arn\":\"arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1:awsaccountid:automation-definition/AWS-StartEC2Instance\",\"Input\":\"{\\\"InstanceId\\\":[\\\"i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\\"]}\",\"Id\":\"aaaaaaaa\",\"RoleArn\":\"arn:aws:iam::awsaccountid:role/some-ssm-role\"}"
```

Or, same thing but marginally more readable this time with caret continuation markers:

```
aws events put-targets ^
    --rule xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ^
    --targets "{\"Arn\":\"arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1:awsaccountid:automation-definition/AWS-StartEC2Instance\",\"Input\":\"{\\\"InstanceId\\\":[\\\"i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\\"]}\",\"Id\":\"aaaaaaaa\",\"RoleArn\":\"arn:aws:iam::awsaccountid:role/some-ssm-role\"}"
```

The key thing to recognize is that the `Input` attribute in the JSON is itself a string containing JSON, so it needs to be double-escaped. This at least passes the initial format validation for me.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much.